# Sublime Text 2 FTP crashing

Tags: ubuntu-11.10, sublimetext, gnome-shell

I'm running ubuntu 11.10 with a gnome-shell and sublime text 2 Beta Build 2180.

When I connect to an FTP server (with login) and I open a file with sublime text 2, I can edit it just fine, that is until I switch to another window.  Then when I switch back sublime text 2 has frozen.  No error message, it just stops responding.

Check Google, Sublime Text forums, to no avail.

Would love some help, it's important to me to be able to edit files over ftp.  Work Arounds would be wonderful as well.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to diagnose your problem from stackoverflow, since it's more Q&A and you seem to have a problem with a specific plugin.  Your best bet is to contact Will Bond, the creator of the plugin.  He will probably want a bug report [i.e. what was displayed in ST2's console (control+`), and any info to reproduce it.]  Here's the support page for the plugin: http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp/support

Comment: I'm not using a plugin. I'm using Ubuntu's ftp application, but maybe I will try the plugin, thanks for the link!

Comment: My mistake.  I just assumed you were referring to the plugin.  I don't really have experience with ubuntu's ftp.  Sorry.  But, yeah, the SFTP plugin is definitely worth a look.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround for the problem, you can use FUSE (Filesystem in Userspace). It will allow you to edit files, like they are on your local machine.

Here is some description on how to setup FTP with FUSE:

http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/344/mounting-ftp-host-to-local-directory-on-top-of-fuse/